# If $f^2$ integrable, then $|f|$ is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

There is a known fact says: if $f^2$ is integrable then $f$ not necessary integrable ($f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$).

But since $f^2=|f|^2$, then one may expect that also $|f|$ not necessary integrable. Is this true, or this previous fact not correct for $|f|$?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually you have $L^1\supset L^2 \supset L^3 ...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|f(x)|\leq1+f(x)^2$$  so: $$\int_a^b|f(x)|dx\leq \int_a^b1+f(x)^2dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, since you are specifying the domain to be the bounded interval $[a,b]$.

Since $f^2$ is integrable it is measurable, which means that $|f| = \sqrt{f^2}$ is also measurable. (The same cannot be said about $f$!) The conclusion is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$\int_a^b |f| \, dx \le (b-a)^{1/2} \left( \int_a^b f^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}.$$

Comment: Don't you need to know that $|f|$ (or $f$) is integrate to begin with ? The space of which this inequality is deduced is the space of integrable functions $f$

Comment: No, as long as $f^2$ has finite integral, so must $|f|$.