# Integrability of $|f$|

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Having $f^2$ integrable over $R$, with $f:R\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded. How does one apply the known result from unidimensional calculus? ([If $f^2$ integrable, then $|f|$ is integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248571/if-f2-integrable-then-f-is-integrable)).
Over the given domain in a rectangle.

Comment: I think you want to say that $R$ is bounded, not $f$.

Comment: Much more generally, if $g:D\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $h:R \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable,, and $h(R) \subset D$, then $g\circ h$ is Riemann integrable.  Here $g(x) = x^{1/2}$ and $h(x) = |f(x)|^2$. The proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2439694/148510) for the 1-D case generalizes easily to the multidimensional case.

Comment: Are you  asking about Riemann or Lebesgue integrals here?

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers in the linked question uses the analogue of the inequality $|f(x,y)| \le 1 + f(x,y)^2$ which is valid for any real number $f(x,y)$. Basic properties of the integral give you
$$\int_R |f(x,y)| \, dxdy \le \int_R 1 \, dxdy + \int_R f(x,y)^2 \, dxdy$$
and your hypothesis is that the right hand side is finite.

Comment: But isn't this just proving it for the particular case of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the concern is if this works undistinguished for all $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I think once you convince yourself that the two-dimensional case doesn't depend on the corresponding one-dimensional result you'll see that it is valid in any number of dimensions.